# AWS DynamoDB access from Android, access denied to table

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to do CRUD operations on a NoSQL DynamoDB, I originally had not integrated a CognitoPool with my project on the AWS Mobile Hub but I have no done that and replaced my json file in the "raw" directory in my project. The DB is completely public both read and write but for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/shoppinglist_unauth_MOBILEHUB_1234567890/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:1234567890:table/ShoppingLists (Service: AmazonDynamoDB; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: BQ0HAP7PUGO6AUC04LOHUND1V3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

I've changed all the identifying numbers to 1234567890 for security reasons.

This is my .json file:

```
{
  "UserAgent": "MobileHub/1.0",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
      "Default": {
        "PoolId": "us-east-1******************,
        "Region": "us-east-1"
      }
    }
  },
  "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
  },
  "CognitoUserPool": {
    "Default": {
      "PoolId": "us-east-1_*******",
      "AppClientId": "5lg571jsd60ruvair8jiqpefbs",
      "AppClientSecret": "bqn8edlp19gfgogfhf4j9qg1mq8u8ftpb328f652n0451gl2dnt",
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  },
  "DynamoDBObjectMapper": {
    "Default": {
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  },
  "PinpointAnalytics": {
    "Default": {
      "AppId": "27e0f3ee2e63419c9dc8f18f23a294fe",
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  },
  "PinpointTargeting": {
    "Default": {
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my onCreate() method in my main activity class

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, awsStartupResult ->
        Log.d("YourMainActivity", "AWSMobileClient is instantiated and you are connected to AWS!"))
        .execute();

// Instantiate a AmazonDynamoDBMapperClient
AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider());
this.dynamoDBMapper = DynamoDBMapper.builder()
        .dynamoDBClient(dynamoDBClient)
        .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
        .build();

Runnable runnable = () -> {
    dbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider());
    // Create a table reference
    dbTable = Table.loadTable(dbClient, "ShoppingLists");
    Document memo = new Document();
    memo.put("Apple", "apple");
    dbTable.putItem(memo);
};
Thread myThread = new Thread(runnable);
myThread.start();
```

My build.gradle should hold the correct dependencies, those are here, granted it may be a bit of a mess:

```
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.18'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.18'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.18'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.6.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-document:2.4.4'
    // Mobile Client for initializing the SDK
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }

    // Cognito UserPools for SignIn
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }

    // Sign in UI Library
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
```

As far as I can tell this should work fine, I was helped by another helpful person here to get to the point where it would connect to AWS which it did do at one point but I just can't seem to access the table.

I guess I have two questions, is it possible to do this without a Cognito pool at all and just have it completely unsecure? And if not, how do I get this to work with the Cognito Pool? Should the cognito pool have user names associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take a crack at answering your questions

1) Can you do this without a Cognito Identity pool? The answer is Yes. This doesn't automatically mean that it is insecure - you can use AWS credentials that you setup for an IAM user. The best practice, however, is to use Cognito Identity pool, which will give you temporary AWS credentials that are valid for a short amount of time.

2) When you create a Cognito Identity pool, two roles (named auth and unauth) are automatically created. The "auth" role is for the cases where you have a signed in user ( for example, signed in using a social login like Facebook and federated to AWS through the Identity pool) and the "unauth" role is for a user who hasn't yet signed in. You can fine-tune the access privileges for these roles using IAM policies to best suit your application's needs.

See this page (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-nosql-integrate-an-existing-table.html) for specific instructions on how to get this working.

Comment: This plus the other person, you guys made my day. This worked very well, thank you so much!